# Is there a way to define wp_blogs domains in wp-config?

Tags: multisite, wp-config

In my multisite setup I have multiple environments that I want to share the same database, but use different domains.

- server1.example.com
- server2.example.com
- example.com

... each of those would point to the same database. This works perfectly fine in a standard WP install using `define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://server1.example.com' );` and `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://server1.example.com' );`.

When you add multisite to the mix it breaks.

**The problem is that the `wp_blogs` table defines the domains too, so I need a way to define them in the config file. Is there anyway to do that?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When WordPress loads multisite, it includes the relevant MS specific files in `wp-settings.php`

The relevant lines:

```
<?php
// Initialize multisite if enabled.
if ( is_multisite() ) {
    require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/ms-blogs.php' );
    require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/ms-settings.php' );
} elseif ( ! defined( 'MULTISITE' ) ) {
    define( 'MULTISITE', false );
}
```

`ms-settings.php` serves a similar purpose as `wp-settings.php`: loads the multisite environment, and -- more importantly for our purposes -- sets up the current site (collection of blogs) and blog. But there's also these few gems:

```
if ( defined( 'SUNRISE' ) )
    include_once( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/sunrise.php' );

/** Check for and define SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL and the deprecated VHOST constant. */
ms_subdomain_constants();

if ( !isset( $current_site ) || !isset( $current_blog ) ) {
    // setup current site and blog
}
```

Most important: `if(defined('SUNRISE'))`.  This lets you drop a `sunrise.php` file in your `wp-content` directory. It gets included if you `define('SUNRISE', true);` in your `wp-config.php`. This file is the same one that's used for domain mapping to setup the current site and blog based on the custom domains.  You can use it to set up your own site and blog rather than let WordPress do it for you.

Quick example -- this works okay, but probably needs some improvement.

```
<?php
// sunrise.php

$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if('wpmscustom.dev' == $host)
{
    // switch the host.
    $host = 'wpms.dev';
}

if(is_subdomain_install())
{
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->blogs} WHERE domain = %s LIMIT 1", $host);
}
else
{
    // this probably needs some work.
    $path = explode('/', ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
    if(count($path))
        $path = '/' . $path[0];
    else
        $path = '/';

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->blogs} WHERE domain = %s AND path = %s LIMIT 1", $host, $path);
}

if($_blog = $wpdb->get_row($sql))
{
    $current_blog = $_blog;

    $blog_id = $_blog->blog_id;
    $site_id = $current_blog->site_id;

    // set current site
    $current_site = $wpdb->get_row(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * from {$wpdb->site} WHERE id = %d", $site_id)
    );
    $current_site->blog_id = $blog_id;

    $current_site = get_current_site_name($current_site);
}
```

Since [@kaiser](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/385/kaiser) will likely chime in to say that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is unreliable, you may want to make sure your server actually has it available.

Or do something like this...

```
<?php
if(isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
{
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
elseif(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
{
    $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}
```

You can drop the above `sunrise.php` into your local install and put `define('SUNRISE', true);` into your local's wp-config.

Comment: +1 and yeah, I would have ;) Btw: Why didn't you link your gist? Another thing (I don't know if this is available for a sunrise DropIn): Could be that you might need to `user_trailingslashit()` depending on the server settings (trailing slash or not).

Comment: Or maybe just do `WHERE path in ('/somepath', '/somepath/')` to catch both?

Comment: That sounds kool - didn't even know this was possible...

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This has gotten me really close. Unfortunately, WP is still looking for some resources on the host I'm overriding. If you the view the source of this page http://trunk.createdenton.com/digital/ you'll see some resources from `staging.` and some from `trunk.`. I need everything to load from trunk and because they're not you're seeing the undefined function error as well.

Comment: Well, I would start by looking at how all those resources are loaded. With an Enqueue (should be)? Or are they directly in the template? Chances are there's a filter you can use to change those URLs -- that's a separate question.

Comment: I modified a couple of things for use here https://gist.github.com/4195012. Namely, I'm using `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` and checking for a custom constant `WP_LOCAL_DEV`. I also integrated @chrisguitarguy's later suggestion of the `WHERE path`.

Comment: I have a more complete solution for this now if you guys wanna take a look. I know it's buggy, so if interested, definitely submit improvements: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75945/3293

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question, but I found this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multiple-domain-with-multisite

Comment: I wish this could work, but it can't.

The first issue is that the point of the domain mapping plugin is to map a site to a domain. That's not exactly what I want. Since my setup consists of `local.example.com/blog1` I can't map it to `staging.example.com/blog1` because it needs that subdirectory. In other words, I'm not looking for domain mapping, just subdomain replacement.

Comment: The second issue is that the plugin requires each environment to be defined in the database itself, rather than the subdomain being defined BY the environment (i.e. in a config file).

What I need to accomplish works perfectly fine in standard WP, just not with multisite.